# Check a cell for valid entry

Tags: excel, reference, cell, cross-reference

I have searched for a solution to this without success, so I'm hoping someone can help me. Please forgive my rudimentary `excel` skills.

I have data with numeric codes in two columns:

**Column A** is called `AREA` and can be any number between 00 - 99

**Column B** is called `TYPE` and can be a number between 00 - 38, but only certain values are acceptable, depending on the `AREA` value.

I have a second set of data that contains all the `AREA` values and the corresponding acceptable `TYPE` values.

Suppose for `AREA` 15, the acceptable `TYPE` values are 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, or 17

My first set of data has a row with `AREA = 15 & TYPE = 23` and based on the above rule, 23 is not an acceptable value for the `TYPE` column.

Is there a way to cross-reference my first set of data (which is a weekly report) with the second set of data (which contains the "rules") to identify those entries with an unacceptable `TYPE` value?

Sorry if I'm not describing this clearly enough. I'm confusing myself just trying to put it into words...

Comment: Can you post a picture of your data?  Are you familiar with conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with data validation and named ranges.

You will need to set up a sheet with the valid choices for each area in a row:
[image: Example]

With your data validation cell for area set to 0 to 99, we will create a named range that will adjust itself for each line of values (remember that 00 is in line 1, 01 in line 2, etc, so you will end up with 100 lines of values)

Name your range something like TypeValues, and enter a formula like this into cell **B2** of your choices sheet:

> =OFFSET(TypeChoices!$A$1,Area!$A2,0,1,COUNTA(INDIRECT("TypeChoices!"&Area!$A2+1&":"&Area!$A2+1)))

what this named range does is to take the value that is in column A, and use that value to find the correct line to look at, count how many values are on that line, and return a list that starts at the appropriate line, and return a list with those values:
[image: DropDowns]
(remember that 4 is line 5, and 3 is line 4, as we initially set it up)

The entry of the formula into B2 is critical, as the named range will not look at the correct area selection otherwise